# Wordpress filtering add_action customization by page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'betterdocs_customize_css');
```

How can I get it to run on a page I specify instead of running it on all internal pages?
Since I added it to the header section, css appears on all unnecessary pages. I only want it to be on one page, how can I filter it?
E.g; Just add it to the header of the domain.com/documents page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like this,

```
add_action('wp_head','betterdocs_customize_css');
function betterdocs_customize_css(){
  //check for the current page is your targeted page by id
  if( is_page( 42 ) ){
     echo "<style> your style here </style>";
  }
}
```

By doing this you can print the style only for your targeted page in the header.

Comment: What about when we want to add multiple page numbers?

Comment: store page ids in an array and use in_array() function to check